# Understanding Functions and the semantics

Tags: javascript

Okay, Please be gentle I am learning Javascript.

I have two buttons (HTML5 `<button>` tags) they are both set to call the same function, In that function is two other functions (show + hide), Now, I am wondering if this is correct, i.e If i click on button hide, it calls function visibility, which then calls the function hide and hides everything defined in this function, including the original buttons. But if i click on button show, it hides the original content and displays extra content, with more buttons.(clickable process throughout)Or is it possible to call these functions separately within this function, For example:

```
    function visible() {
    function show() {
        slide = document.getElementById('side');
        pos = 0;
        move = setInterval(slider, 1000/60);
        slide1 = document.getElementById('main');
        pos1 = 100;
        move1 = setInterval(slider1, 1000/60);

        document.getElementById('welcomer').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = 'none';

            function slider() {
                    if (pos == 20) {
                        clearInterval(move);
                    }else {
                        pos++;
                        slide.style.display = 'block';
                        slide.style.width = pos + '%';
                    }
                }
            function slider1() {
                if (pos1 == 80) {
                    clearInterval(move1);
                }else {
                    pos1--;
                    slide1.style.width = pos1 + '%';
                }
            }   
        }
    function hide() {
        slide = document.getElementById('side');
        pos = 0;
        move = setInterval(slider, 1000/60);
        slide1 = document.getElementById('main');
        pos1 = 100;
        move1 = setInterval(slider1, 1000/60);

        document.getElementById('welcomer').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = 'none';

            function slider() {
                    if (pos == 20) {
                        clearInterval(move);
                    }else {
                        pos++;
                        slide.style.display = 'block';
                        slide.style.width = pos + '%';
                    }
                }
            function slider1() {
                if (pos1 == 80) {
                    clearInterval(move1);
                }else {
                    pos1--;
                    slide1.style.width = pos1 + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    document.getElementById('vis').addEventListener('click', show());
    document.getElementById('invis').addEventListener('click', hide());
}
```

Or is it semantically correct not to have nested functions, Instead to have the two separate functions, and call the functions separately onclick. For example:

```
    function show() {
    slide = document.getElementById('side');
    pos = 0;
    move = setInterval(slider, 1000/60);
    slide1 = document.getElementById('main');
    pos1 = 100;
    move1 = setInterval(slider1, 1000/60);

        document.getElementById('welcomer').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = 'none';

        function slider() {
                if (pos == 20) {
                    clearInterval(move);
                }else {
                    pos++;
                    slide.style.display = 'block';
                    slide.style.width = pos + '%';
                }
            }
        function slider1() {
            if (pos1 == 80) {
                clearInterval(move1);
            }else {
                pos1--;
                slide1.style.width = pos1 + '%';
            }
        }
    }
function hide() {
    slide = document.getElementById('side');
    pos = 0;
    move = setInterval(slider, 1000/60);
    slide1 = document.getElementById('main');
    pos1 = 100;
    move1 = setInterval(slider1, 1000/60);

        document.getElementById('welcomer').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('welcome').style.display = 'none';

        function slider() {
                if (pos == 20) {
                    clearInterval(move);
                }else {
                    pos++;
                    slide.style.display = 'block';
                    slide.style.width = pos + '%';
                }
            }
        function slider1() {
            if (pos1 == 80) {
                clearInterval(move1);
            }else {
                pos1--;
                slide1.style.width = pos1 + '%';
            }
        }
    }
```

Or is it possible, for the button hide, do i just create an array, with every ID/Class Element i want to hide, call it with the onclick on the button to hide and then change the style to `display: none;` for all elements in that array?.
And vice versa for the divs i would create with button show?

Now i understand alot of this can be deemed opinionated, So the reason i am asking is this: I want to know which would be the quickest method using vanilla javascript, which way would shorten the amount of code and reduce loading time, with the best possible outcome based on facts.

**Please note I have had to write this code with pretty much zero knowledge as i am *learning* Javascript, These are primarily for example, and both show/hide do the exact same thing for now, ultimately the show function will create more divs and content etc.**

Comment: I suggest you add some code on jsfiddle? The convolution you have here is hard to understand without a proper example.

Comment: Okay, I will have to write the code up, I got as far as the outline... and then pondered on this question, will update shortly

Comment: Is the function in question a known bottleneck? Or is this more of a "how can I preoptimize my code" type of question?

Comment: @Dom it is more of a best practise for preoptimisation, aswell as helping me to understand the function capabilities if that makes sense?

Comment: Do not post code elsewhere, links rot. You can post runnable snippets here. This seems to be more about code practice and application architecture than a programming question so not really suitable for SO.

Comment: We need to see more code context to understand the choices you're asking about.  It is correct to define local functions at no higher a scope than needed.

Comment: It all depends on the `/* bunch of variables */` and what the `/* Input code to show/hide onclick */` exactly does. No, it is totally fine to declare functions inside other functions, and often even very beneficial for appropriate scoping.

Comment: @RobG How is this not a programming question?, The question is aimed at helping to understand the Programming elements within Javascript Programming to get a better understanding of how things work, and the best possible way to do it. It has everything to do with Programming, especially for someone who is learning like myself and wish to know more.

Comment: Okay people, I have primarily added some code, to hopefully show what i am asking, apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having nested functions is perfectly acceptable, and often desirable or even necessary. The syntax would be as follows for doing so :

```
function base_function(){
    this.function_1 = function(){};
    this.function_2 = function(){};
}
```

This defines a function constructor with two values... function_1 and function_2. You could then call either of them using the following

```
var base = new base_function();
base.function_1();
```

Now, if you only need to reference those child functions within the scope of the base_function, something like the following would suffice.

```
function base_function(){
    function child_function_1(){}
    function child_function_2(){child_function_1();}
}
```

Think of `function` as it is in js, a datatype, like a string or numeric type. You can pass it to variables, reference it later on in code, pass it as a callback (like in `setTimeout`, you pass the reference to the function as a varaible. i.e. `setTimeout(function_1,1000)` rather than `setTimeout(function_1(),1000)`). You can also declare functions using `var function_1 = function(){}` because of this (and is my preferred method).

Because of the way javascript handles functions, you can do some interesting and super cool stuff with them - such as closures or IIFYs! [Here is a great explanation of these and how to use them](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-closures-callbacks-iifes/)!

To answer your question, I would suggest going with the first route, while retaining a variable inside the function referencing the content you want to display/hide. Even if it means you need to write a few extra lines, it makes the code much more readable when you keep things modular, and readability really is king in most circumstances.

Something like this

```
var Vis_Controller = function(content){
    this.content = content;
    this.hide = function(){
        content.style.display = "none";
    }
    this.show = function(){
        content.style.display = "block";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    var button_show = document.getElementById("button-show");
    var button_hide = document.getElementById("button-hide");
    var vis_controller = new Vis_Controller(content);
    button_show.addEventListener("click",vis_controller.show);
    button_show.addEventListener("click",vis_controller.hide);
});
```

Comment: That is not a prototype object  - its a constructor function.

Comment: You are correct, I'll update it appropriately. I tend to use the terms interchangeably, tbh, since all functions retain a reference to a prototype of that function's constructor... Useful if you want static-esque access (Among other potential benefits).

Comment: May i Ask, Why was this down voted? Also I kind of understood your first two code previews, but you lost me on the third with this: function child_function_2(){child_function_1();} Why would you need to call function_1 in function_2 if (i Presume) they are already defined and seperate but can be accessed by base_function? But the rest of it pretty much answers my question.

Comment: Hi, sooo... If you have heard of encapsulation in other languages ( public/protected/private ), then in my third example it would be similar to having private methods. You could use both of those functions within base_function, but if ( later in your code ) you declare a variable containing base_function (var x = new base_function()), you wont be able to use the child functions outside of base_function's scope :) As for the downvotes, who knows. Someone might think underscores are an abomination? Sadly, a lot of people on this site tend to choose downvoting over being constructive.

Comment: (You'll also find that if you ask a question which is slightly open ended, people will often comment with something along the lines of 'instructions unclear, xyz caught in ceiling fan', even for basic questions like this)